# Binding DataGrid to List in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a `List` to a `DataGrid`.
Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Parson
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public Parson(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        FirstName = firstName;
    }
}

public class Persons : List<Parson>
{
    // Parameterless constructor      
    public Persons()
    {
    }
    public new void Add(Person parson)
    {
        base.Add(parson);
    }
}
```

the code behind:

```
Persons persons = new Persons();
persons.Add(new Parson("New","Person");
dataGrid1.DataContext = persons;
```

xaml:

```
<my:DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" 
             xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
             CanUserAddRows="True" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

The result is that an empty grid is displayed!
Anyone know why?

Comment: The xaml:

<my:DataGrid  Name="dataGrid1" 
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
        CanUserAddRows="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
            </my:DataGrid.Columns>
        </my:DataGrid>

Comment: Does your Output-Window contain anything related to this binding?

Comment: Your code runs and works for me. Where are you setting the grid's DataContext? I set it in Window.Loaded.

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.  Lastly, fix your spelling errors.  A Parson is a type of priest.  Spelling errors will kill you in bindings, as there is no type safety.

Comment: Where do you call this code behind ? In the constructor of window or elsewhere ?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `AutoGenerateColumns = true`

Answer (score 5):

(Note:  This answer was verified in .NET Framework v4.0):

A simple, 4-part operation...

- first, on your DataGrid control in the XAML mark-up I recommend you set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` (you should be able to do this manually better than they can do it automatically)
- second, on the same control set `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, which informs the grid it will be getting it's column and row data from a source not defined at design-time.
- third, construct the columns to look how you want them to look and for each bind to the column data with something like `Binding="{Binding Path=UniqueID}"`.  Note that the value after Path is interpolated so mind things like case-sensitivity.  For the List<> you are targetting the value will presumably be one of the property-names from objects in your target List<>.  Rinse and repeat as many times as needed for each column in your DataGrid.
- fourth, in your form code-behind, within the constructor or during form load or wherever it best suits your needs, set the DataContext of your grid.  This should take a form similar to `{gridControlName}.DataContext = {target-List<>}`

When the form is loaded its grid should auto-populate with content from objects in the your List<>.

Comment: I also had to make sure that all the DataGrid columns referred to class properties (e.g. public int MyColumn { get; set; }) and not just class fields (e.g. public int MyColumn; )

Comment: And setting the .DataContext property needs to happen sometime after InitializeComponent() is called

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ItemsSource instead of DataContext, and remove the `ItemsSource={Binding}` from your XAML. That may do the trick.

Edit:

I just checked some code I wrote that uses the same DataGrid control (WPF Toolkit), and I do in fact set the ItemsSource instead of DataContext. If you need an example, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your DataGrid try:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"
```

This has worked sucessfully for me.